# Upgrading PHP version on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade the version of PHP installed on an Ubuntu server 10.10 from 5.3.3 to 5.3.6. I followed the instructions at http://wiki.helioviewer.org/wiki/Compiling_PHP_from_source_on_Ubuntu and all seemed to go well, but when I run phpinfo() it's still showing the old version. If I run php -version from the command line it says 5.3.6. What do I need to do to get Apache to use this version?
Thanks

Comment: Perheps you can ask the question also in http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you restarted apache

This have to be on [askUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com) though

Comment: Yes, restarted Apache but no joy. Will try askUbuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restart Apache indeed

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

However, I did had some problems in the past that the apache process got stuck in the memory after a recompile / or PHP upgrade. If you want to check if apache is still running after you've stopped it:

Stop Apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

Look for apache processes

```
ps -A | grep apache
```

If you get a list with some apache2 processes it's not good, you can kill them with:

```
kill <PROCESS_ID>
```

For example:

```
kill 2389
```

Start apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Comment: Restarting didn't work, so I went through the instructions again and it's now at 5.3.6 :-)